# webdriver-manager update error: EACCES, permission denied

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor

I used to run Protractor tests successfully (on Mac) and I tried to upgrade version, so I ran

```
$npm install -g protractor
```

and it seemed like it worked - when running

```
$protractor --version
```

I get

```
Version 1.8.0
```

but now, when running

```
$webdriver-manager start
```

I get

```
 fs.js:642
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
             ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium'
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:642:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-     manager:108:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to run `webdriver-manager update` with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -s
$ webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: But if I am running selenium server through test programatically for example in protractor.conf through seleniumadress how do that?

Comment: Thanks, that did help, I did try earlier too, to run the whole command with sudo, that didnt work.