# protractor sets error without opening browser

Tags: protractor

i download a new ionic project and i am trying to test the header contains these elements ""

my config file is

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['../www/head.spec.js'],
  multiCapabilities: [
  {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }]
}
```

named this as e2e.js

my test case file is

```
    describe('header Module', function(){

        var header;      

       beforeEach(function() {
             header = element(by.css('title'));             
        });

it('should check title text',function(){
            expect(header.getText()).toContain('Ionic Blank Starter');

        });
    });
```

and i named this as head.spec.js

my issue is that i could see the browser opened and my protractor sends an error msg

> empresss-Mac-mini:myApp admin$ protractor test/e2e.js 
>   Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:172
>         callback(new Error(message));
>                  ^
>   Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
>       at ClientRequest. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:172:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:259:9)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
>       at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
>       at process.*tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
>   From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession* (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:157:22)
>       at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:131:30)
>       at [object Object].Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:445:22)
>       at [object Object].DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:38:7)
>       at [object Object].Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:182:37)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:263:21
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:759:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:525:49
>   [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

could someone help to fix this issue

when i try to  webdriver-manager update err msg is displayed

```
empresss-Mac-mini:~ admin$ webdriver-manager update
fs.js:799
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:799:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager:126:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
empresss-Mac-mini:~ admin$
```

Comment: Have you started a webdriver manager in a separate process? ([docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial#setup))

Comment: few doubts i installed  protractor globally. Webdriver-manager should be installed inside the ionic project or to be installed globally. i tried but it gives this err  "empresss-Mac-mini:~ admin$ webdriver-manager update
fs.js:799
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), "

Comment: If you installed protractor globally, then webdriver manager should be available globally too. Just run `$ webdriver-manager update` and after it finishes downloading - `$ webdriver-manager start`

Comment: If you struggle to post the error text in comments, you can edit original question and add info in there.

Comment: `Error: EACCES: permission denied` is an issue with permissions in your file system. Whether or not you used `sudo` to install protractor, you'll have to use it to work with webdriver now, because of global installation: `$ sudo webdriver-manager update`. Check out similar Q/A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079021/webdriver-manager-update-error-eacces-permission-denied).

Comment: wow now my browser is opening but next issue is browser opens in address bar ip is displayed and after few sec it disappears and displays "Data;" then my browser closed and all my test are been displayed as err that is red in colour. and also all other browser are been closed automatically, only test browser is opened

Comment: There should be an error message in your terminal (in red), where you can find error description. Just a wild guess: try to remove `beforeEach()` block from your test. Also, I think it is worth of creating a new question, because they are not related to each other.

Comment: thank you  Michael Radionov